# Can you implode an array into function arguments?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to have an array and pass it into a function as separate arguments?

```
$name = array('test', 'dog', 'cat');
$name = implode(',' $name);
randomThing($name);

function randomThing($args) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // Would be 'test', 'dog', 'cat'

    print_r($args);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. That's what [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is for.

Answer (score 9):

As of PHP 5.6 you can use `...` to pass an array as function arguments. See this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-150) from the PHP documentation:

```
function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

echo add(...[1, 2])."\n";

$a = [1, 2];
echo add(...$a);
```

Comment: "... can also be used when calling functions to unpack an array or Traversable variable or literal into the argument list"