# Spread array data as function arguments after a single variable is used as the first parameter

Tags: php

I have an associative array:

```
$percentageAndRepData = [
    1 => [
        "main" => [0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 5, 5, 5],
        "assistance" => [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 10, 10, 10]
    ],
    2 => [
        "main" => [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 3, 3, 3],
        "assistance" => [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 8, 8, 6]
    ],
    3 => [
        "main" => [0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 5, 3, 1],
        "assistance" => [0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 5, 5, 5]
    ],
    4 => [
        "main" => [0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 5, 5, 5],
        "assistance" => [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 5, 5, 5]
    ]
];
```

And I have a function:

```
function liftCalculator ($trainingMax, $firstSetPercentage, $secondSetPercentage,
$thirdSetPercentage, $firstSetReps, $secondSetReps, $thirdSetReps)
```

User input will provide `$trainingMax`, but I want every other element in the `"main"` and `"assistance"` arrays to correspond to the rest of the `liftCalculator`'s parameters.

So on `"main"` I want to pass `0.65` as `$firstSetPercentage`, `0.75` as
`$secondSetPercentage,` and so on. Then the same on `"assistance"`, and then repeat for every week.

I've googled methods to pass arrays as arguments into a function but couldn't find one that allows me to provide the first argument with a different method. All examples I found assumed all parameters in the function come from array elements.

Comment: Also: [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744145/2943403) and [Function to create objects by passing an array of parameters to __construct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65362550/2943403) and [Can you implode an array into function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10272230/2943403) and [Pass array to varargs function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41907201/2943403)